# Mounting a Windows XP dd image fails

Tags: linux, image, mount

I have a Windows XP dd image. I'm checking the image with the file command:

```
    root# fdisk -l ./hdddump.img

    Disk ./hdddump.img: 2031 MB, 2031400960 bytes, 3967580 sectors
    Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk label type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0xef8b000a

            Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
    ./hdddump.img1              63     3354623     1677280+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    ./hdddump.img2         3354624     3967487      306432    b  W95 FAT32
```

Afterwards I'm trying to mount the image:

```
    root# mount -t auto -o loop,ro,noexec,offset=32256 hdddump.img ./hddmount/
    mount: /absolute_path/hdddump.img: failed to setup loop device: numerical result out of range
```

I have no idea why this happens and I can't find any hint in the internet. Converting the image with qemu-img and including it as harddisk in a VM Ware machine works, so the image isn't broken.

Comment: How is this question programming-related ?

Comment: Sorry for posting the question here. Is it possible to move it to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding sizelimit=858767360 to your mount options. Maybe there's a problem if losetup (called by mount) tries to auto-calculate the size.

(858767360 =1677280*512)

But this question would better be asked on superuser or maybe serverfault.

Comment: It works with sizelimit, but the correct size seems to be 1717566976 = 512 * 3354623.